# Add a column to indicate presence of an item in different time stamps

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset which has tree measurements at time t1 and t2. These trees are identified by state, county, plot and tree number. There are some trees that have died in the time interval between t1 and t2.

```
State   County   Plot    Tree     Meas_yr
1       9        1       1        t1 
1       9        1       2        t1
1       9        1       3        t1
1       9        1       1        t2
1       9        1       2        t2
```

I am trying to create a binary label which gives 1 to trees if they are present in both t1 and t2 and 0 to trees if they are present in t1 but not present in t2. I am hoping to create something like this.

```
State   County   Plot    Tree     Meas_yr  tree_survival
1       9        1       1        t1       1
1       9        1       2        t1       1
1       9        1       3        t1       0
1       9        1       1        t2       1
1       9        1       2        t2       1
```

I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have a follow up question. Similar to the dataset above, there are new trees that have grown in time t2 which were not present in time t1. How do I create another label where the trees that are only present in t2 is 1 and others are zero.

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(State, County, Plot, Tree) %>%
    mutate(available = +('t2' %in% Meas_yr))
```

Comment: I guess you meant `('t2' %in% Meas_yr)`

Answer (score 2):

If we want to check for the trees that survived between `t1` and `t2` the code below works.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(State, County, Plot, Tree) %>% 
  mutate(tree_survival =  +all(c("t1", "t2") %in% Meas_yr))
```

---

---

---

To identify every variation, the code below works:

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(State, County, Plot, Tree) %>% 
  mutate(tree_survival =  +('t1' %in% Meas_yr) + +all(c("t1", "t2") %in% Meas_yr))
```

This will give you the following identifiers:

- 0 = if only present at `t2`.
- 1 = if present at `t1` only, but died later on.
- 2 = if present at both `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I have a follow up question. Similar to the dataset above, there are new trees that have grown in time t2 which were not present in time t1. How do I create a similar label where the trees that are only present in t2 is 1 and others are zero.

Comment: ```+('t1' %in% Meas_yr) + +all(c("t1", "t2") %in% Meas_yr)``` this will give you 1 for only t1, 2 for t1 and t2, and 0 for only t2.

Comment: @sakar299 see above;

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  group_by(State, County, Plot, Tree)%>%
  mutate(availble = +(!all(Meas_yr == 't1')))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   State, County, Plot, Tree [4]
  State County  Plot  Tree Meas_yr availble
  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <int>
1     1      9     1     1 t1             1
2     1      9     1     2 t1             1
3     1      9     1     3 t1             0
4     1      9     1     1 t2             1
5     1      9     1     2 t2             1
6     1      9     1     4 t2             1
```